# Eigenvectors not in the Underlying Hilbert Space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Eigenvectors for the momentum operator: $P=-i\dfrac{d}{dx}$ are functions $f_p(x):=e^{ipx}$ which are not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. The notion of orthogonality can be made rigorous by use of Fourier transform which allows us to represent a general $L^2$ function as a superposition of functions $e^{ipx}$.

quoting wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Spectral_theorem
"Other versions of the spectral theorem are similarly intended to capture the idea that a self-adjoint operator can have "eigenvectors" that are not actually in the Hilbert space in question."

Can anyone provide other examples of eigenvectors for self-adjoint operators that are not in the underlying Hilbert space of the operator and the strategies to prove that they are, in fact, eigenvectors?
(i am most interested in examples involving trigonometric functions.)

Comment: Adding a local potential won’t change the far-field behavior, so $H=p^2/(2m)+V(x)$ is going to have a continuum of non-$L_2$ eigenvectors.  Verifying that they are eigenvectors just amounts to checking that the differential equation $H\psi = E\psi$ is satisfied (where $E$ is the eigenvalue).

Comment: @Max You might be interested in [rigged Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space).

Comment: excellent. thanks @BenGrossmann

Comment: Eigenvectors are in the space. You're looking for a way to expand the context so that you have eigenfunctions that are not in $L^2$. One way to do this is the through the spectral theorem, where you consider absolutely continuous spectrum, meaning that $\langle E(\lambda)x,y\rangle$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$, where $E(\lambda)$ is the spectral projection associated with $(-\infty,\lambda]$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

$e_{\lambda}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{i\lambda x}$ is an eigenfunction of $L=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$, and $Le_{\lambda}(x)=\lambda e_{\lambda}$, but it is not an eigenvector in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. However, the following *is* in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and is an *approximate* eigenvector:
\begin{align}
   e_{\lambda,\epsilon}(x)&=\int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon} e_{\lambda'}(x)d\lambda' \\
     &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon}e^{i\lambda' x}d\lambda' \\
     &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}ix}(e^{i(\lambda+\epsilon)x}-e^{i(\lambda-\epsilon)x}) \\
     &=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{i\lambda x}\frac{\sin(\epsilon x)}{x}.
\end{align}
The $L^2$ norm of $e_{\lambda,\epsilon}$ can be determined from the Plancherel identity:
$$
      \|e_{\lambda,\epsilon}\|_{L^2}^{2}=\int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon}1d\lambda'=2\epsilon.
$$
Note that
$$
    \|Le_{\lambda,\epsilon}-\lambda e_{\lambda,\epsilon}\|^2=\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon}(\lambda'-\lambda)e^{i\lambda' x}d\lambda'\right\|^2 \\
       = \int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon}(\lambda'-\lambda)^2d\lambda'=\frac{2\epsilon^3}{3}
$$
Therefore
$$
              \|(L-\lambda I)e_{\lambda,\epsilon}\|^2=\frac{\epsilon^2}{3}\|e_{\lambda,\epsilon}\|^2.
$$